# How to put an array in wp user query

Tags: array, wp-user-query

I am quite new to php and wordpress developement, and I am also new to this website. I want to learn development by trial and error. Please forgive me if i don't use all proper terminology.

I have some code that gets the following id's for a user in buddypress. I would like to use these values in a loop and check the member types of the buddypress user.

I have 3 member types, and the end result should output an array of user ID's per member type.

Below code fetches the user ID's for members being followed by current user.

`$following = bp_get_following_ids( $user_id) ;
print_r (explode(" ",$following));`

Above code gives an output like e.g. : Array ( [0] => 2,3,4,5,6,8,14 )
I would like to use this array in a user query

`$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'include' => array( 1, 2, 3 ) ) );`

where 1,2,3 should be the output of the code above.

I have tried below, but that seems to be wrong.

`$user_query = WP_User_Query( array( 'include' => explode(",",$following)));`

How can i get the array into the query so i can create a loop to check the users by member type and output the ID's ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the [`wp_parse_id_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_id_list/) function. It will return an array of unique IDs, sanitized with the `absint()` function:

```
$csv = bp_get_following_ids();

if( 0 !== $csv ) )
{
    $uids       = wp_parse_id_list( $csv );
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( [ 'include' => $uids ] );
}
```

where we assume that `bp_get_following_ids()` returns a *comma-seperated* string of user IDs on success or integer zero on failure.

### Example

If we take a comma seperated string, with some "dirty" values:

```
$csv = "1a,2!,3";
```

and

```
$uids  = wp_parse_id_list( $csv );
```

then

```
var_dump ( $uids )

array (size=3)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
```

and

```
print_r( $uids):

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can't vote yet, but the help is surely appreciated!

Comment: you're welcome, glad to hear it worked for you @eGuard